# How can I create X_Y_Z_M point feature from xls file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point

How can I create xyzm point feature from xls file?
I m working on ArcGis10, I have also available QGIS. 
My end product will be polyline zm, but first I need to create correctly point zm. I have million of records to be changed. I have coordinates X, Y, Z and M (event)

Comment: What software or platform are you using? In wich format you would like the feature?

Comment: And with which what programming interface, on what platform, and in what context?  Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of the details expected in questions here at GIS SE.

Comment: Typically, when you want to create M values (measures), you need to have a linear feature.  Please edit your question to include more details such as what you have tried, what software you're using, do you have a linear feature?  How many?  What fields are in your spreadsheet?

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with XYZM points. There is much to measure from points.

Comment: I believe that it can be done rather easily with the GDAL VRT driver but support for measures in VRT is brand new and documentation does not contain examples yet. Other possibility that might work is to use spatialite-gui.

Answer (score 1):

Think this would be a 2 process thing (in Arc anyways). Create an event theme (or run Make XY Event Layer) and then use the z and m values from the attribute fields in the resulting feature to populate the geometry values. I would do something in Python, but you could run "Feature To 3D By Attribute". I'm not sure what an m value represents in your point feature, but if it is even supported I think you might be stuck with Python for that. There is also a newer tool (10.2.2) that looks like it would work for this step (Add Geometry Attributes).